# file_get_contents return all php code

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to send a POST request to some file when I load index.php. I use this code:

```
$query = http_build_query(array('ajax' => 'gwonline', 'session' => $current_session));
$contextData = array ( 
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                            "Connection: close\r\n".
                            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                'content'=> $query );
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));
$result =  file_get_contents(PATH::Includes . 'ajax.php', false, $context);
$result_decoded = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<div id="gwonline">' . ($result_decoded['isonlinestr'] ?: '<span class="fa fa-circle" style="color:orange"></span> Unavailable') . '</div>';
```

The problem is, `$result` ends with getting the PHP code instead of whatever the file actually printed. How can I fix it without changing the site to `http://...` as it's not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` just loads a file. It doesn't execute it, parse it or whatever. Just the text.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include` with output buffering.  file_get_contents is reading the file from the filesystem, it isn't going to use PHP to analyze it.  The only reason it works when you use `http://` is because then the web server is serving the file, not the filesystem.

```
ob_start();
include "ajax.php";
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: How can I use `include` with a `POST` request?

Comment: I need it to get parameters, so it knows what to return.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing.  All that is unnecessary if you are loading a local file.  You shouldn't be setting headers and methods.   Whatever is set in your script will be passed to the included file, so set what you need, better yet: create a function or class for this.

Comment: Can I set something in $_POST on runtime?